# convert URL's hex digits into a string

Tags: c#, url, hex

I need to convert a url with hex digits to its equivelant string so that I can parse the query for e.g.

> http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=c%23+windows+service+timer&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c114b5df3c1901b1

--> c%23 = C#

how can I go about it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Uri.UnescapeDataString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know there was a method available to do that :) saved me a lot of time.